# Ragdoll effect in box 2d

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I want to make a body with ragdoll effect.  How this can be achieved in box2d. I want to body keep straight even it fall down it can stand up itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of basic ragdoll tutorials.

To make it stand you could do the following:

### 1.

Make the joints springy. Make the joints have a target angle and a motor torque to resist rotation and move them back into a standing position.

### 2.

Use a force to lift the character up.

```
if (headBody.position.y < normalHeadHeight) {
   headBody.applyForce(b2vec2zero, b2vec2(0,100));
}
```

This will lift the character up off the ground if their head goes below its normal height.

### Notes

If you want it to look more like the character is really alive and moving under their own free will it will take a lot more work.

Comment: my character is a football player and it can lift leg on button press.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Look up "Box2D ragdolls" and you'll find lots of basic examples of ragdolls. I've suggested a method to make them stand up and go back to a normal position.